# RabbitMQ "BasicAck," is halting execution

Tags: c#, mono, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ setup where the code is 100% similar to the second tutorial.  For some unkown reason my "workers," would stop accepting new messages.  After hunting it down, the line:

`channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);`

Is halting the program execution.  I found this out my putting some print statements around the line.  I'm wondering why this may be happening.

I'm using the C# API, running on Mono.  All workers are only handling one message at a time.  I do have multiple workers using the same login info for the RabbitMQ server.

Comment: Are you getting back an exception when you make this call? Is it wrapped in a try/catch?

Comment: No, there isn't a try/catch block around it.  I would assume that if there was an exception thrown it would kill my program.  Should I do this instead?

Comment: Always worth wrapping it in a try/catch, just to make sure any exceptions can be caught and debugged, rather than being in a situation where something doesnt work and you have no idea whats going on

Comment: I did a little more testing with my code, it seems to be that the chances are much higher that it will hang on the ACK message if my job takes longer to process.

Comment: Ok. A bit stumped TBH. To confirm: Do you have 1 IModel per worker? When you get the message, are you setting the consumption to wait for an ACK? Before you make the call on IModel to BasicAck, can you confirm the connection to RabbitMQ has not died? (Due to single threading kill the heartbeat or something?)